# Finding list of radio buttons with a class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have radio buttons YES and NO in every row of a table column which is populated by data from back end. If it is a yes, then yes radio is checked and if no then no radio is checked, and if no data comes then both remain unchecked. Both of them have same class 'QtytobePacked1' defined in their input tags.
What i want to do using jquery is, that if there is no data from back end then there is a submit button that should be disabled. And when yes or no is selected by user then the submit button should enable. 
Also this check should run for all the yes and no radio buttons in all the row for that column.
This is the code for radio buttons (ignore disabled attribute):

```
<%
    String yesno = list.get(i).get(16);
    if(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
        ++yesinc;
    %>
    <td style="width: 9%; ">    <!--Material Test Certificate Attached -->
      Yes<input type="radio" class="QtytobePacked1"  name="noteryes<%=(yesinc) %>" value="Yes" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"> No<input class="QtytobePacked1" type="radio" name="noteryes<%=(yesinc) %>"  value="No" disabled="disabled">
    </td>
    <%} else if(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
        ++noinc;
        %>
    <td style="width: 9%;">    <!--Material Test Certificate Attached -->
      Yes<input type="radio" class="QtytobePacked1" name="noterno<%=(noinc) %>" value="Yes" disabled="disabled"> No<input class="QtytobePacked1" type="radio" name="noterno<%=(noinc) %>" value="No" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"> 
    </td>
                                    <% 
    } else {
        ++inc;
    %>
    <td style="width: 9%;">    <!--Material Test Certificate Attached -->
      Yes<input type="radio" class="QtytobePacked1"  name="noter<%=(inc) %>" value="Yes" disabled="disabled"> No<input class="QtytobePacked1" type="radio" name="noter<%=(inc) %>" value="No" disabled="disabled"> 
    </td>
    <% } %>
```

This is code for submit button:

```
<div class="buttonDiv" align="center">
    <button class="upload_button_inactive" id="save_button" type="submit" name="exp_save_button" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code? What is the HTML? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: updated the code.

Comment: Hi I have applied similar checks to 3 other text box which are in every row of the table. Even if single one of them is empty, the submit button is disabled. I did this by using bind in jquery. But i dont know how to access all the radio buttons of a table using common class name. And how to decide which one is filled and which one empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access all the input components that are **RADIO type**, you can use these jquery selectors, you have many options:

```
$('.QtytobePacked1') 

$('[type="radio"]') 

$('td > input')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand how radio buttons work together in groups, and from there I think it will be pretty simple to apply to your needs now, and in the future.

a group of radio buttons, per HTML compliance, need to have different ID's, but to get their values, the `name` attribute needs to be the same per each ground.

knowing this, your yes/no grouped should look, something like:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdYes" name="question1" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" id="rdNo" name="question1" value="No" />
```

this way, a simple: `$("input[name=question1]:checked").val()` will give you `Yes` or `No` depending on the checked radio button and also prevent one or more radio's to be selected at the same time.

moreover, to have the name `Yes` to be also clickable, we normally use the `label` HTML tag together with the id of the input tag, like:

```
<label for="rdYes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="rdYes" name="question1" value="Yes" />
```

or without the `for` attribute

```
<label>
    Yes <input type="radio" id="rdYes" name="question1" value="Yes" />
</label>
```

this way, not only the radio button is clickable, but also the word.

here's a live example how radio buttons work: https://jsbin.com/katodilito/1/edit?html,js,output

---

As I look at your code, and maybe everyone else, is that you are repeating yourself, and that's the first rule of a developer, to never repeat yourself, so allow me to help you with refactoring the code a bit.

1 - let's move the table cell constraints outside your if else block as you are repeating them all the time, and makes it a bit too much:

```
<td style="width: 9%; ">    <!--Material Test Certificate Attached -->
<%
  String yesno = list.get(i).get(16);
  if(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
     ++yesinc;
%>    
  Yes<input type="radio" class="QtytobePacked1"  name="noteryes<%=(yesinc) %>" value="Yes" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"> No<input class="QtytobePacked1" type="radio" name="noteryes<%=(yesinc) %>"  value="No" disabled="disabled">
<%} else if(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
    ++noinc;
    %>
  Yes<input type="radio" class="QtytobePacked1" name="noterno<%=(noinc) %>" value="Yes" disabled="disabled"> No<input class="QtytobePacked1" type="radio" name="noterno<%=(noinc) %>" value="No" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"> 
    <% 
} else {
    ++inc;
%>
  Yes<input type="radio" class="QtytobePacked1"  name="noter<%=(inc) %>" value="Yes" disabled="disabled"> No<input class="QtytobePacked1" type="radio" name="noter<%=(inc) %>" value="No" disabled="disabled"> 
<% } %>
</td>
```

2 - we can now easily focus on the statement, but that's a big statement for all you need is `checked` attribute to be selected...

```
<td style="width: 9%; ">    <!--Material Test Certificate Attached -->
<%
  String yesno = list.get(i).get(16);
  if(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
     ++yesinc;
  } else if(yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
    ++noinc;
  } else {
    ++inc;
  }
%>

 <label for="rdYes<%=(yesinc) %>">Yes</label> 
 <input type="radio" id="rdYes<%=(yesinc) %>" 
        class="QtytobePacked1" name="noteryes<%=(yesinc) %>" 
        value="Yes" 
        <%= yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("YES") ? "checked='checked'" : "" %> />

 <label for="rdNo<%=(yesinc) %>">No</label> 
 <input type="radio" id="rdNo<%=(yesinc) %>" 
        class="QtytobePacked1" name="noteryes<%=(yesinc) %>" 
        value="No"
        <%= yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("NO") ? "checked='checked'" : "" %> />
</td>
```

makes things a little better to read right?